# In MySQL, how string containing numbers be searched?

Tags: mysql

Here is a table structure :  Table name - UTEF_P

```
id   location   name
1    Place A    AA/1
2    Place Z    AA/2
3    Place T    AA/3
4    Place Y    AA/4
5    Place T    AA/5
6    Place I    AA/6
7    Place U    AA/7
8    Place J    AA/8
9    Place H    AA/9
10   Place O    AA/10
```

Now, if I run this query : -  `Select * from UTEF_P where name >= 'AA/1' and name <= 'AA/10'`, it returns me only 2 records in stead of 10 records.
So, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Store the string component and the numeric component separately

Answer (score 2):

That's right, alphabetical order is not particularly intuitive on numbers.

My advice would be to just include all possible values:

```
Select *
from UTEF_P
where name IN ('AA/1', 'AA/2', 'AA/3', 'AA/4', 'AA/5',
    'AA/6', 'AA/7', 'AA/8', 'AA/9', 'AA/10');
```

This way the query can be indexed. Alternatively, you could extract the substrings and cast to number, but performance is not likely to be nice:

```
Select *
from UTEF_P
where substr(name from 1 for 3) = 'AA/'
and cast(substr(name from 4) as decimal) between 1 and 10;
```

Last but not least, the need for such a numerical search in a text column may be a symptom of data not being stored in the most optimal format.

Comment: At 90.3k *this* is your advice. You must know something I don't :-(

Comment: @Strawberry My rep comes mainly from PHP stuff and I'm still learning anyway. If I'm giving some terrible piece of advice please tell me. Certainly, it's possible that explicit casting is not strictly necessary and maybe a regexp search performs better—I didn't really create a table and test all possibilities.

Comment: I think a revised design would be a better idea

Comment: @Strawberry That's what I try to express with the last paragraph but I simply didn't dare being so categorical. One sample query is not representative enough to figure out the overall data domain; there may be other codes with an entirely different format and numeric search may not be representative or even useful in general terms.

Comment: Well, FWIW, I think you've eaned the right to be a little more categorical ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the basic concept, `>=` or `<=` can only be used with numerical values. As the values you are dealing with are `string`, in that case the two results you are getting because of the `=` part with `>`. That `=` match with the two string, that's it is returning two results only.

Instead try REGEXP:

```
WHERE name REGEXP '[0-9]'  // It search for a pattern match with in the string
```

[REGEX Reference](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-regexp-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the mysql column value and then check for values

```
Select * from UTEF_P where SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'/',-1) BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

I suppose you can split 1 and 10 from the respective parameters in your respective language.

And if you want to match AA also then use

```
Select * from UTEF_P where SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'/',-1) BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND name LIKE 'AA%' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work if I want to filter name > AA/1 :
`select * from UTEF_P where left(name,2) > 'AA' and substr(name,locate("/", name)+1) > '1';`

Answer (score 0):

Your range search (`>=`) is now on string ranges, therefore it compares string based on **alphabetical order**: `'AA/10' < 'AA/9'`.
Try casting:

```
Select * 
from UTEF_P 
where cast(mid(name,3),INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```